# Copying partial list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to collect the output from a system command that lists tickets (strings) separated by new lines. I specify what 'lastTicket' is and I want to copy the full list until I reach lastTicket. I'm getting the following error, "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" on line 5 below. How can I copy only the portion of the list that I need? Thanks.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)

allTickets = output.rstrip().split('\n')

idx = len(allTickets)
for ii in allTickets:
    if lastTicket in allTickets[ii]:
        idx = ii
        break

print idx

tickets = allTickets[idx:len(allTickets)]
```

Comment: I think the error is actually line 7 (the one with `allTickets[ii]` in it). Does that help you? Try printing `ii` before that line.

Comment: What the need to call your temporary variable 'ii' instead of just 'i' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use either

```
for ii in range(len(allTickets)):
    if lastTicket in allTickets[ii]:
        idx = ii
        break
```

BTW are you sure you want `if lastTicket in allTickets[ii]:` and not `if lastTicket == allTickets[ii]:`?

Comment: The latter doesn't make sense. (What is `ii`?)

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks. How do I index inside of this list? Say if I want to print the 3rd element of 'tickets'?

Comment: Not quite sure what list you are talking about, but the 3rd element of 'tickets' would just be `tickets[2]`. (indices are 0 based in python)

Comment: for ii in tickets:
        print tickets[ii]

gives me an error that "list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: `for ticket in tickets: print ticket` or `for ii in range(len(tickets)): print tickets[ii]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to get an index:

```
for idx, ticket in enumerate(allTickets):
    if lastTicket in ticket:
        break
print idx
tickets = allTickets[idx:]
```

Answer (score -1):

`li` is value in the `allTickets` (which I guess is String). You are passing that to get value `allTickets[ii]`. Array/list index are always integers.

I think you are looking for something like:

```
for index, val in .........
      if lastTicket in allTickets[index]:
```

Comment: If you're not going to use `val`, then `for index in range(len(allTickets))` is probably better.

Comment: @smarx: Agree, I was not sure what OP req, so gave answer on that lines.